# When using recv(n), with n greather than the MTU are you guaranteed to read at least a whole layer 2 frame?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I was wondering, imagine if there is no data to read from a TCP socket, then a whole frame of 1492 bytes arrives (full). In your code (C or any language supporting TCP) you have let's say recv 4096 bytes, will the OS guarantee that the recv reads the whole 1492 bytes, or is it possible that the loading of the frame in memory and recv are "interleaved", so the recv may get less ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is a stream oriented protocol. Data are received in order but you must not do any assumption about how many times you have to call recv until you receive all your data.
It is up to your application to repeat the calls to recv until you know you have received what you need.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** TCP is stream-oriented protocol. This means that it accepts a stream of data from the upper layer on the sender and returns the stream of data to the upper layer on the receiver. TCP itself receives packets from IP layer, and then reconstructs the stream. That is at some points packets cease to exist. In theory it is possible that somewhere during this reconstructed stream, only half of the incomming packet is copied in buffer, but it seems to me pretty unlikely that this would happen.

Now, linux [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) states

> The receive calls normally return any data available up to the requested amount,

I would interpret it as "if one packet has arrived (correctly, in order, etc), you will get the whole packet worth of data". But there is no guarantee.

On the other hand [Windows docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv) states:

> recv will return as much data as is currently available—up to the size of the buffer specified.

Which sounds more like the guarantee.

Note, however, that the data will only be returned if the packet is received correctly, and it is next in-order packet (with next expected sequence numbers).

**(2)** Now, TCP layer works on complete packets. It is actually impossible for it to do interleaving or anything. Ethernet has a checksum, which cannot be computed unless the packet was received completely. Packets with incorrect Ethernet checksum should be filtered out by the network card. TCP also has a checksum which requires all packet data to compute. So, if the network card has passed the packet to your OS, then data should be available.

**(3)** I don't think you can assume that if the packet is received, it is immediatelly available. A pretty common feature of network cards is TCP segmentation offload, which reconstructs part of the stream and results in network card passing one TCP packet that was reconstructed from multiple TCP  packets. There are other things that can be in place to reduce the number of interrupts, which more or less result in several packets comming at once. So, the more likely situation is that you will have maybe some delay and then receive data from several packets at once.

The point is, the opposite of what you described is likely to happen. However, I still would not write an application that makes any assumptions about how large a chunk of data is available at a time. This negates the concept of a stream.